# Solving complex equation $z^5-2\bar{z}|{z}|^2 = 0$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I'm having some trouble understanding how to solve the following complex equation:

$$z^5-2\bar{z}|z|^2 = 0$$

I did find this other question [Solve the complex equation $w^3=9\overline{w}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294877/solve-the-complex-equation-w3-9-overlinew) that helped me realize that I could see mine as

$$z^5 =2\bar{z}|z|^2$$

And writing $z$ with the exponential form $e^{i\theta}$ and rewriting it

$$r^5e^{5i\theta}=2r^3e^{-i\theta}$$

This lead me to having $r=\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\frac{k\pi}{2}$. I think that from here I just need to solve with:

$$z=\sqrt{2} \left(\cos{\frac{k\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{k\pi}{2}} \right)$$

However I'm not sure for which are the actual solutions, to which $z_k$ I should be solving and why

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your title as well as in your post.

Comment: Here $r^5e^{5i\theta}=2r^2e^{-i\theta}$ should be $r^3$ on the RHS. This influences the rest of your computation.

Comment: @user376343 you're right I fixed that

Comment: The equation $e^{6i\theta}=1$ has six solutions ${\theta}_k=\frac{k\pi}{3}$ with $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$ 
The six solutions to the given equation in cis form are $z_k=\sqrt{2}(\cos\frac{k\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{3}).$

Comment: @user376343 where did $e^{6i\theta} = 1$ come from?

Comment: I think I got it but I'd like to see your answer too, and anyways you'd deserve that upvote :D

Comment: I think all you missed was that you know two important facts about $r$ that tell you everything you need about $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know already, absolute value of each solution is $\sqrt 2.$

For the argument:
The equation $e^{5i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}$ is equivalent to $$e^{6i\theta}=1,$$ which has six solutions ${\theta}_k=\frac{k\pi}{3}$ with $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$
The six solutions to the given equation in cis form are $$z_k=\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{k\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{k\pi}{3}\right),\quad \text{where}\quad k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can see that $z=0$ is clearly a solution. So for the rest of this, assume $z<>0$.

Writing in polar form is the right idea (we've only got two terms); putting $z=re^{i\theta}$, with $r,\theta$ real and $r>0$,
$$\begin{align}
z^5&=2\overline{z}|z|^2 \\
r^5 e^{5i\theta} &= 2r e^{-i\theta} \cdot r^2 \\
r^2 &= 2e^{-6i\theta} \end{align}$$

Now, the left-hand side is real and positive, so we need the same for the right-hand side. This gives us the condition
$$6i\theta=2k\pi$$

for some integer $k$. Also $r^2=2$ so we have $r=\sqrt{2}$  (since $r>0$).

Finally, we can write down the solutions $z=0$ or
$$z=\sqrt2 e^{\frac{ni \pi}{3}}$$
where $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how: "so we need the same for the right-hand side" leads to the condition you mentioned?

Comment: Sure. The expression on the RHS represents a point on the unit circle centred at $0$ in the complex plane. There's only one point on that circle that's real and positive, ie $z=1$.